# rosdep can't find cyclonedds during foxy install

Tags: ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [install doc](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/) but the step where I should install the rosdep dependencies results the following error:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths ros2-linux/share --ignore-src --rosdistro foxy -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps osrf_testing_tools_cpp poco_vendor rmw_connext_cpp rosidl_typesupport_connext_c rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 tinyxml_vendor tinyxml2_vendor urdfdom urdfdom_headers"
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
rmw_cyclonedds_cpp: No definition of [cyclonedds] for OS version [bionic]
```

I get a bit further with the `-r` option but when I try to source ROS2 it still throws this error:

```
y$ . ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/setup.bash
[connext_cmake_module] Warning: The location at which Connext was found when the workspace was built 
[[/opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1]] does not point to a valid directory, and the NDDSHOME environment variable has not been set. Support for Connext will not be available.
```

Ubuntu 18.04 / foxy

I had a melodic install on my machine

I reinstalled and updated python3-rosdep

Any idea how could I proceed with the install? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357803/rosdep-can%27t-find-cyclonedds-during-foxy-install/) by [carlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/56898/carlb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely the issue comes from the fact that you are trying to install ROS 2 Foxy on Ubuntu Bionic,  which is not a supported platform of ROS 2 Foxy. From the [install doc you linked](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/#system-requirements):

> "We support Ubuntu Linux Focal Fossa
> (20.04) 64-bit x86 and 64-bit ARM."

To find out what OS are supported by the different versions of ROS 2 you can refer to [REP-2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html).

This is why it cannot find a Foxy package for `cyclonedds` on your Ubuntu Bionic environment.

You could ignore the `cyclonedds` issue and try to use the default implementation (Fast-RTPS) but you're likely to hit other issues as you go since you're trying to use it on an unsupported platform.

---

More likely to succeed solutions would be to use an older version of ROS 2 that targets your version of Ubuntu (such as [ROS 2 Dashing](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#dashing-diademata-may-2019-may-2021)), or to migrate to Ubuntu Focal (20.04) and use ROS 2 Foxy

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/56898/carlb/) on 2020-07-22**:
Oh, thanks a lot! I totally missed that.